# Attributes from PropertyPath

Tags: attributes, properties, binding

If i have a PropertyPath, is it possible to get it's attributes? If not, what minimum of info do i need? From the example i need to get SomeAttribute. I need for it my custom binding class.

Eg.

Test.xaml

```
<TextBox Text={Binding SomeValue}/>
```

Test.xaml.cs

```
[SomeAttribute]
public string SomeValue { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

By PropertyPath you can take only property or subproperties.
Read [data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an attribute of bound property with reflection technique.

The following is sample code.

**SomeEntity.cs**

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    [SomeAttribute]
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow" ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="textBox" Text="{Binding SomeValue}"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Button</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new SomeEntity();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get bound object from TextBox.DataContext.
        object obj = this.textBox.DataContext;

        // Get property name from Binding.Path.Path.
        Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(this.textBox, TextBox.TextProperty);
        string propertyName = binding.Path.Path;

        // Get an attribute of bound property.
        PropertyInfo property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        object[] attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SomeAttribute), false);
        SomeAttribute attr = (SomeAttribute)attributes[0];
    }
}
```